# Use of CSAttributes in new pages

Tags: acumatica

We have a new page where we are looking to use the CS Attributes similarly to how they are used in the Item Class and Non Stock item pages

- Item Class: Attribute definition.
- Non Stock item page: Attribute implementation.

[image: Attribute definition in the Item Class page]

[image: Attribute use in the NonStockitem page]
**NOTE**: I simplified the page to narrow down any potentially needed attributes in the ASPX.

Based on this, my Attribute definition page has the following elements:

Graph:

```
#region Datamembers
public PXSelect<MDEquipmentType> EquipmentType;

[PXViewName("Attributes")]
public CSAttributeGroupList<MDEquipmentType, MDEquipment> Mapping;
#endregion
```

ASPX:

```
<px:PXTabItem Text="Attributes">
            <Template>
                <px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Height="150px" Style="z-index: 100;
                    border: 0px;" Width="100%" ActionsPosition="Top" SkinID="Details"  MatrixMode="True">
                    <Levels>
                        <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="Mapping">
                            <RowTemplate>
                                <px:PXSelector CommitChanges="True" ID="edAttributeID" runat="server" DataField="AttributeID" AllowEdit="True" FilterByAllFields="True" />
                            </RowTemplate>
                            <Columns>
                                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="IsActive" AllowNull="False" TextAlign="Center" Type="CheckBox" />
                                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="AttributeID" Width="81px" AutoCallBack="true" LinkCommand="CRAttribute_ViewDetails" />
                                <px:PXGridColumn AllowNull="False" DataField="Description" Width="351px" />
                                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="SortOrder" TextAlign="Right" Width="81px" SortDirection="Ascending" />
                                <px:PXGridColumn AllowNull="False" DataField="Required" TextAlign="Center" Type="CheckBox" />
                                <px:PXGridColumn AllowNull="True" DataField="CSAttribute__IsInternal" TextAlign="Center" Type="CheckBox" />
                                <px:PXGridColumn AllowNull="False" DataField="ControlType" Type="DropDownList" Width="81px" />
                                <px:PXGridColumn AllowNull="True" DataField="DefaultValue" Width="100px" RenderEditorText="False" />
                            </Columns>
                        </px:PXGridLevel>
                    </Levels>
                    <AutoSize Enabled="True" MinHeight="150" />
                </px:PXGrid>
            </Template>
        </px:PXTabItem>
```

Result:
[image: Our page result]

So far so good, all records are persisted in the DB correctly in the table CSAttributeGroup

Now, the problem comes when I try to apply the attributes in the data entry page.

This is the page:
[image: Attribute not shown]

When the Equipment Type is set, the attribute grid does not populate.

Graph definition:

```
  public class MDEquipmentEntry : PXGraph<MDEquipmentEntry, MDEquipment>
    {
        #region Datamembers
        public PXSelect<MDEquipment> Equipment;

        public CRAttributeList<MDEquipment> Answers;
```

ASPX:

```
   <px:PXTabItem Text="Attributes">
        <Template>
            <px:PXGrid ID="PXGridAnswers" runat="server" Caption="Attributes" DataSourceID="ds" SkinID="Inquire" Width="100%" Height="200px" MatrixMode="True">
                <Levels>
                    <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="Answers">
                        <Columns>
                            <px:PXGridColumn DataField="AttributeID" />
                            <px:PXGridColumn DataField="isRequired" TextAlign="Center" Type="CheckBox" Width="80px"/>
                            <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Value" Width="300px" AllowShowHide="False" AllowSort="False" />
                        </Columns>
                        <Layout FormViewHeight="" />
                    </px:PXGridLevel>
                </Levels>
                <AutoSize Enabled="True" MinHeight="200" />
                <ActionBar>
                    <Actions>
                        <Search Enabled="False" />
                    </Actions>
                </ActionBar>
                <Mode AllowAddNew="False" AllowColMoving="False" AllowDelete="False" />
            </px:PXGrid>
        </Template>
    </px:PXTabItem>
```

In the Nonstock item page the attribute is loaded immediately after inserting the Item Class. So I made sure that the commitChanges attribute was added to my page. Also looked for a FieldUpdated event that could be triggering the insertion but that does not appear to be needed.

What could be missing from my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of `CRAttributeList` depends on a class ID field being defined somewhere in your class. Upon initialization, `CRAttributeList` will look for a field in your `MDEquipment` DAC decorated with the `CRAttributesField` attribute.

For the `InventoryItem` DAC, here's how it is defined:

```
    [CRAttributesField(typeof(InventoryItem.itemClassID))]
    public virtual string[] Attributes { get; set; }
```

If system is unable to determine the current class ID, your attributes grid will not be populated with anything.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks @Gabriel